# Laravel4: upload a photo

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, photo-gallery

I'm stuck..
I want to add to give the possibity to add a new photo through a form.
I have the Photo resource properly set up.
The table photo with: id, title, caption, path:string.

This is the form that i made until now in the view photo.create:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'photos.store'),'image/save', array('files'=> true)) }}

 {{ Form::label('title', 'Title: ') }}
 {{ Form::text('title') }}

 {{ Form::label('caption', 'Caption: ') }}
 {{ Form::textarea('caption') }} <br>

 {{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}

 {{ Form::close() }}
```

How can i add a button thanks to which select a new file?

Thank you!!

EDIT:

This is the simple store method i made until now:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array('title' => 'required', 'path' => 'required');

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->passes()) 
    {

        $photo = new Photo();
        $photo->title = $input['title'];
        $photo->caption = $input['caption'];
        $photo->path = $input['path'];

        $photo->save();

        return Redirect::route('photos.index');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('message','There were validation message');

}
```

How can i put correctly there that implementation to retrieve the file and store in the folder located in public/img ?
And then how can i save that path and put into $photo->path ?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Form::file('image')`

Then, you can retrieve your uploaded file with `Input::file('image')` and move it to a destination with `Input::file('file')->move(YOUR_DESTINATION_PATH);`

References : http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files and http://laravel.com/docs/html#file-input

---

**edit :**

To store your uploaded file to `public/img` : `Input::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/img');`

Storing path in database :

```
$photo->path = base_path() . '/public/img' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(); // if you want your real path on harddrive
```

or

```
$photo->path = URL::to('img/' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName()); // if you want an exploitable path for http render
```

---

**second edit**
See my correction on your form http://paste.laravel.com/KX9

```
@extends('master')
@section('blog')
<div class="span12 well">
    {{ link_to_route('photos.index', 'Back to index') }}
</div>

<div class="span12 well">
   {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'photos.store', 'files'=> true)) }}
     {{ Form::label('title', 'Title: ') }}
     {{ Form::text('title') }}
     {{ Form::label('caption', 'Caption: ') }}
     {{ Form::textarea('caption') }} 
     {{ Form::label('image', 'Image: ') }}
     {{ Form::file('image') }}
     <br>
     {{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}
   {{ Form::close() }}
   <br><br>
   @if($errors->any())
      {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
   @endif
</div>
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand how to make the form.
Can you please help me also to fix the store method?

Comment: I have inserted 
Input::file('image')->move(base_path() . '/public/img');
in the first line of the store method, but i get this error:
Call to a member function move() on a non-object

Comment: Can you see what is transmitted to Laravel, via a debug console ?

Comment: THis is the error: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…\app\controllers\PhotosController.php36

And the line is this: Input::file('image')->move(base_path() . '/public/img');

Comment: What about dumping Input::file('image') ?

Comment: it gives null..
Strange because in the form there is this for the file:

     {{ Form::label('image', 'Image: ') }}
     {{ Form::file('image') }}

Comment: Maybe this line is wrong:
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'photos.store'),'image/save', array('files'=> true)) }}

Comment: You have to keep files => true, because your form has to be sent with multipart/form-data. Check what is sent on POST data.

Comment: array (size=4)
  '_token' => string 'iVzXhE28PwkLrxkgew0d0vTO9sznzcZ7YLnc9wtN' (length=40)
  'title' => string 'Photo1' (length=6)
  'caption' => string 'Caption1' (length=8)
  'image' => string 'IMG_1085.JPG' (length=12)

Comment: You haven't any multipart data ?

Comment: what means? I have to insert something in the form?

Comment: Normally, with files => true, you have not to do this ... I don't see why it isn't working.

Comment: If you want, i put here the view Create:
http://paste.laravel.com/KX1

it should be here the issue, no?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Form::file('image');`

see http://laravel.com/docs/html#file-input

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@upload', 'files'=>true)) }}
{{ Form::label('image', 'Upload Image')}}
{{ Form::file('image') }}
{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Step2:

```
public function upload(){
    $image = Input::file('image');
    $savepath = 'public/uploads/';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('image')->move($savepath, $filename);
}
```

Final Step:

```
Route::get('/upload' function()    
{
    return View::make('upload');    
});    
Route::post('/upload', 'HomeController@upload');
```